# Using purrr to map right-hand-side variables to regression functions

Tags: r, purrr

I have a large number of regression models specified by reference to right-hand-side variables, and I want to use `purrr` to generate a set of lists with the models. Here is an example of the desired end result using toy data:

```
m.1.1 <- "cyl"
m.1.2 <- paste(c(m.1.1, "disp"), collapse = " + ")


m.1.1_reg <- lm(
  data = mtcars,
  formula = as.formula(paste0("mpg ~ ", m.1.1)))


m.1.2_reg <- lm(
  data = mtcars,
  formula = as.formula(paste0("mpg ~ ", m.1.2)))
```

How can I achieve the same outcome (i.e., a list named m.1.1_reg and another list named m.1.2_reg) using `purrr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the 'm.1.' objects in `map` and create the formula

```
library(purrr)
out <- map(dplyr::lst(m.1.1, m.1.2), 
    ~ lm(data = mtcars, formula = as.formula(paste0("mpg ~ ", .x))))
```

-checking the names

```
> names(out)
[1] "m.1.1" "m.1.2"
```

Comment: Thanks -- this code runs the models, but it doesn't put the results in lists for further analysis.

Comment: @nicholas the ouptut from `map` is a `list`.  If you meant to assign to an object, do `out <-map(...`

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for the same output as yielded by the sample code. So, a list named m.1.1_reg and another list named m.1.2_reg.

Comment: @nicholas that is easiler, we can loop over named list i.e. `dplyr::lst` does it automaticlaly, or use `list(m.1.1 = m.1.1, m.1.2 = m.1.2)` or `mget(ls(patterns = '^m\\.1")) %>% map(~ ...`

Comment: I would recommend to keep it in a list rather than creating multiple objects with `assign` or `list2env`

Comment: @nicholas I updated the post.  Can you check it